# Redis 1+ min query time on lists with 15 larger JSON objects (20MB total)

Tags: redis

I use Redis to cache database inserts. For this I created a list `CACHE` into which I push serialized JSON lists. In pseudocode:

```
let entries = [{a}, {b}, {c}, ...];
redis.rpush("CACHE", JSON.stringify(entries));
```

The idea is to run this code for an hour, then later do an

```
let all = redis.lrange("CACHE", 0, LIMIT);
processAndInsert(all);
redis.ltrim("CACHE", 0, all.length);
```

Now the thing is that each `entries` can be relatively large (but far below 512MB / whatever Redis limit I read about). Each of the `a, b, c` is an object of probably 20 bytes, and `entries` itself can easily have 100k+ objects / 2MB.

My problem now is that even for very short `CACHE` lists of only 15 entries a simple `lrange` can take many minutes(!) even from the `redis-cli` (my `node.js` actually dies with an *"FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory"*, but that's a side comment).

The debug output for the list looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> debug object "CACHE"
Value at:00007FF202F4E330 refcount:1 encoding:linkedlist serializedlength:18104464 lru:12984004 lru_seconds_idle:1078
```

What is happening? Why is this so massively slow, and what can I do about it? This does not seem to be a *normal slowness*, something seems to be fundamentally wrong.

I am using a local Redis 2.8.2101 (x64), ioredis 1.6.1, node.js 0.12 on a relatively hardcore Windows 10 gaming machine (i5, 16GB RAM, 840 EVO SSD, ...) by the way.

Comment: Instead of using `JSON.stringify()`, have you considered using the `Hash` data type of redis? You can use the MULTI command to individually save all the hashes, and then store the keys of those hashes in your list. (The MULTI command will do this in one round trip).

Comment: Hm, what benefit would that give? Shouldn't I rather use MULTI with RPUSH then?

Comment: That is what I meant, sorry, to use a MULTI command for first saving the hashes and then adding their keys to the list. But, I have to ask, is there a reason for storing the whole cache in one key, and then retrieving the whole cache every time? Transfer of very large data can have heavy performance costs.

Comment: Perhaps add here the output of `SLOWLOG GET`

Answer (score 1):

Redis is great at doing lots of small operations, 
but not so great at doing small numbers of "very big" operations.

I think you should re-evaluate your algorithm, and try to break apart your data in to smaller chunks. Not only you'll save the bandwidth, you'll also will not lock your redis instance long amounts of time. 
Redis offers many data structures you should be able to use for more fine grain control over your data.

Well, still, in this case, since you are running the redis locally, and assuming you are not running anything else but this code, I doubt that the bandwidth, nor the redis is the problem. I'm more thinking this line:

```
JSON.stringify()
```

is the main culprit why you are seeing the slow execution.

JSON serialization of 20MB of string is not something simple, 
The process needs allocate many small strings, and also has to go through all of your array and inspect each item individually. All of this will take a long time for a big object like this one.

Again, if you were breaking apart your data, and doing smaller operations with redis, you'd not need the JSON serializer at all.

Comment: Well, not quite. I just tested it, here is the result (on my 5y old work notebook): `creating (107 ms), size: 2097152 elements`,
`stringifying (2043 ms), size: 228589569 bytes`, `converting back (3527 ms), size: 2097152 elements`. [Source](http://pastebin.com/KicFaFJk) (`guid()` is just a function that does what it says). And I just realized these times are for 200MB, not 20MB.

Comment: well - 200MB is probably pushing you to the Redis's limit. 
Still, you need to re-architect your algorithm. Saving everything and recovering everything is not scalable.